# JSONLD for Google AMP with php-json-ld

Tags: php, schema.org, json-ld, amp-html

I have problems printing the correct JSONLD for Google Accelerated Pages (AMP, www.ampproject.org) with "php-json-ld" (github.com/digitalbazaar/php-json-ld) as documented in this example: github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/examples/metadata-examples/article-json-ld.amp.html

More specifically: I am wondering how to add the **"@type": "NewsArticle"** by using the functions of php-json-ld:

```
    $doc = (object)array(      
    "https://schema.org/article" => 'Article',
    "http://schema.org/name" => "Manu Sporny",
    "http://schema.org/url" => (object)array("@id" =>     "http://manu.sporny.org/"),
    "http://schema.org/image" => (object)array("@id" => "http://manu.sporny.org/images/manu.png")
);

    $context = (object)array(
    "article" => (object)array("https://schema.org/Article"),
    "name" => "http://schema.org/name",
    "homepage" => (object)array("@id" => "http://schema.org/url", "@type" => "@id"),
    "image" => (object)array("@id" => "http://schema.org/image", "@type" => "@id")
);

    //Print Json-LP
    echo '<script type="application/ld+json">';
    echo json_encode($jsonld_compacted, 
                JSON_PRETTY_PRINT | JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
    echo '</script>';

    //Result:
    <script type="application/ld+json">{
       "@context": "http://schema.org",
       "image": "http://manu.sporny.org/images/manu.png",
       "name": "Manu Sporny",
       "url": "http://manu.sporny.org/"
   }</script>
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you don't need to transform the JSON-LD, you don't need php-json-ld (or any other library). A simple associative array that you serialize as JSON is enough:

```
$data = array(
  "@context" => "http://schema.org",
  "@type" => "NewsArticle",
  ...
);

...

echo json_encode($data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT | JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
```

Comment: Now that's one epic tip/answer from [one of the authors of the JSON-LD specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/json-ld/).

Comment: Wish I'd read this before I'd tried three of them.

Answer (score 6):

A big thanks to the answer of [Markus Lanthaler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2400004/markus-lanthaler) which helped me a lot. I only have a small addition to his answer:

If you are using variables like the post_title, the characters are automatically encoded which will result in in a badly formatted JSON-LD.
The way to counter this, is by first decoding the variable like the title:

```
html_entity_decode(get_the_title($post->ID),ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8');
```

And on echoing the json_encode, you should add the JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE as well, for the right encoding.

So your echo should than look like this:

```
echo json_encode($data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT | JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```